# Does Visual Studio 2017 support a _references.js file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

my JavaScript Intellisense is broken in Visual Studio 2017.  I know my _references.js file is correct as JS Intellisense works fine in VS2015.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you used the VS 2017 RC or VS 2017 RTM version which was released on March 7? How did you added the _references.js file into your project?

Comment: I am using  VS 2017 RTM version which was released on March 7.  I added _references.js file by right clicking on "scripts" folder and adding new JavaScript file.  I also notice that window.intellisense doesn't exist!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You no longer need a `_references.js` file. IntelliSense in VS 2017 works a little differently than it used to.

Are you trying to use a specific library or just get IntelliSense from your own code? If it's a library, it needs to have a `.d.ts` file. If it is your own code, it might depend on if you are using a module system or not.

You can read more about how it works here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense

Comment: Thanks for this.  Wish it had been easier to find.

Comment: Where did you look for this first? I would love to make it more discoverable.

Comment: You can read about this change further down on this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio.md

Comment: I'm using MS Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.7.6  Support _references.js seems to have been added back.  Yay.